# Using HttpClient with SSL - override the Credential Required pop-up

Tags: .net, ssl, httpclient

I am using the HttpClient with SSL connection but when I either use Automatic or the Manual Store method of attaching a certificate I get a Windows Security dialog with a prompt asking to confirm "Do you want to allow the app to access your private key?"

Even if I select "Allow", every time my app re-authenticates it asks me Allow the credentials. How do I ensure that the HttpClient makes a request without getting the pop-up shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out myself in the end. Previously the certificate was installed onto the local user account and stored within the users own cert store. Once we installed the cert as local machine and within the trusted section it was fine.